Native Build Fails for Quarkus with AWS ServiceDiscovery Dependency Due to Unsupported Method java.lang.Object.wait0(long)
I'm encountering a fatal error while trying to build a Quarkus application natively using the mvn clean package -Pnative command. The build fails when I include the software.amazon.awssdk:servicediscovery dependency from the AWS SDK. The error indicates that the method java.lang.Object.wait0(long) is unsupported during the native image build process with GraalVM.
Github Link To the code
Actual Behavior:
The native build fails with the following error:
com.oracle.svm.hosted.substitute.DeletedElementException: Unsupported method java.lang.Object.wait0(long) is reachable
To diagnose the issue, you can add the option --report-unsupported-elements-at-runtime. The unsupported element is then reported at run time when it is accessed the first time.

Error Output:
[1/8] Initializing...                                                                                   (10.1s @ 0.30GB)
 Java version: 21.0.3+7-LTS, vendor version: Oracle GraalVM 21.0.3+7.1
 Graal compiler: optimization level: 2, target machine: x86-64-v3, PGO: ML-inferred
 C compiler: cl.exe (microsoft, x64, 19.39.33523)
 Garbage collector: Serial GC (max heap size: 80% of RAM)
 7 user-specific feature(s):
 - com.oracle.svm.thirdparty.gson.GsonFeature
 - io.quarkus.caffeine.runtime.graal.CacheConstructorsFeature
 - io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.graal.DisableLoggingFeature: Disables INFO logging during the analysis phase
 - io.quarkus.runner.Feature: Auto-generated class by Quarkus from the existing extensions
 - io.quarkus.runtime.graal.DisableLoggingFeature: Disables INFO logging during the analysis phase
 - org.eclipse.angus.activation.nativeimage.AngusActivationFeature
 - org.hibernate.graalvm.internal.GraalVMStaticFeature: Hibernate ORM's static reflection registrations for GraalVM
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 4 experimental option(s) unlocked:
 - '-H:+AllowFoldMethods' (origin(s): command line)
 - '-H:BuildOutputJSONFile' (origin(s): command line)
 - '-H:-UseServiceLoaderFeature' (origin(s): command line)
 - '-H:+GenerateBuildArtifactsFile' (origin(s): command line)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Build resources:
 - 23.91GB of memory (75.6% of 31.64GB system memory, determined at start)
 - 20 thread(s) (100.0% of 20 available processor(s), determined at start)
WARNING: A Java agent has been loaded dynamically (D:\personal\workspace\temp\quarkus-with-aws\target\quarkus-with-aws-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-native-image-source-jar\lib\net.bytebuddy.byte-buddy-agent-1.14.15.jar)
WARNING: If a serviceability tool is in use, please run with -XX:+EnableDynamicAgentLoading to hide this warning
WARNING: If a serviceability tool is not in use, please run with -Djdk.instrument.traceUsage for more information
WARNING: Dynamic loading of agents will be disallowed by default in a future release
[2/8] Performing analysis...  []                                                                        (11.2s @ 1.90GB)
   12,600 reachable types   (79.5% of   15,856 total)
   14,654 reachable fields  (48.9% of   29,944 total)
   55,760 reachable methods (51.1% of  109,030 total)
    4,175 types,   133 fields, and 2,918 methods registered for reflection
        4 native libraries: crypt32, ncrypt, psapi, winhttp

Fatal error: org.graalvm.compiler.debug.GraalError: org.graalvm.compiler.debug.GraalError: com.oracle.svm.hosted.substitute.DeletedElementException: Unsupported method java.lang.Object.wait0(long) is reachable
To diagnose the issue, you can add the option --report-unsupported-elements-at-runtime. The unsupported element is then reported at run time when it is accessed the first time.
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.AnalysisFuture.setException(AnalysisFuture.java:49)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:322)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.AnalysisFuture.ensureDone(AnalysisFuture.java:63)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.heap.ImageHeapObjectArray.readElementValue(ImageHeapObjectArray.java:84)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.heap.ImageHeapScanner.onObjectReachable(ImageHeapScanner.java:464)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.heap.SVMImageHeapScanner.onObjectReachable(SVMImageHeapScanner.java:156)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.heap.ImageHeapScanner.lambda$markReachable$5(ImageHeapScanner.java:452)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.heap.ImageHeapScanner.lambda$postTask$14(ImageHeapScanner.java:695)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.CompletionExecutor.executeCommand(CompletionExecutor.java:187)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.CompletionExecutor.lambda$executeService$0(CompletionExecutor.java:171)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1423)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:387)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1312)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1843)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1808)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:188)
Caused by: org.graalvm.compiler.debug.GraalError: com.oracle.svm.hosted.substitute.DeletedElementException: Unsupported method java.lang.Object.wait0(long) is reachable
To diagnose the issue, you can add the option --report-unsupported-elements-at-runtime. The unsupported element is then reported at run time when it is accessed the first time.
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.AnalysisFuture.setException(AnalysisFuture.java:49)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:322)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.AnalysisFuture.ensureDone(AnalysisFuture.java:63)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.heap.ImageHeapScanner.getOrCreateImageHeapConstant(ImageHeapScanner.java:212)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.heap.SVMImageHeapScanner.getOrCreateImageHeapConstant(SVMImageHeapScanner.java:109)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.heap.ImageHeapScanner.createImageHeapConstant(ImageHeapScanner.java:186)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.heap.ImageHeapScanner.lambda$createImageHeapObjectArray$3(ImageHeapScanner.java:270)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: com.oracle.svm.hosted.substitute.DeletedElementException: Unsupported method java.lang.Object.wait0(long) is reachable
To diagnose the issue, you can add the option --report-unsupported-elements-at-runtime. The unsupported element is then reported at run time when it is accessed the first time.
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.substitute.AnnotationSubstitutionProcessor.lookup(AnnotationSubstitutionProcessor.java:268)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.infrastructure.SubstitutionProcessor$ChainedSubstitutionProcessor.lookup(SubstitutionProcessor.java:140)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.meta.AnalysisUniverse.lookupAllowUnresolved(AnalysisUniverse.java:438)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.meta.AnalysisUniverse.lookup(AnalysisUniverse.java:417)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.meta.AnalysisUniverse.lookup(AnalysisUniverse.java:78)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.infrastructure.UniverseMetaAccess.lookupJavaMethod(UniverseMetaAccess.java:112)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.meta.AnalysisMetaAccess.lookupJavaMethod(AnalysisMetaAccess.java:83)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.reflect.ReflectionFeature.createAccessor(ReflectionFeature.java:187)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1740)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.reflect.ReflectionFeature.getOrCreateAccessor(ReflectionFeature.java:141)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.reflect.target.ExecutableAccessorComputer.transform(ExecutableAccessorComputer.java:43)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.substitute.ComputedValueField.computeValue(ComputedValueField.java:366)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.substitute.ComputedValueField.readValue(ComputedValueField.java:336)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.ameta.AnalysisConstantReflectionProvider.readHostedFieldValue(AnalysisConstantReflectionProvider.java:235)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.heap.SVMImageHeapScanner.readHostedFieldValue(SVMImageHeapScanner.java:124)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.heap.ImageHeapScanner.createImageHeapInstance(ImageHeapScanner.java:287)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.heap.ImageHeapScanner.createImageHeapObject(ImageHeapScanner.java:254)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.heap.ImageHeapScanner.lambda$getOrCreateImageHeapConstant$2(ImageHeapScanner.java:205)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)

Environment:

Quarkus Version: 3.14.1
Java Version: 21.0.3 (Oracle GraalVM 21.0.3+7.1)
GraalVM Version: Oracle GraalVM 21.0.3+7-LTS-jvmci-23.1-b37
Maven Version: Apache Maven 3.9.8


Does anyone have suggestions on how to resolve this issue or prevent the java.lang.Object.wait0(long) method from being reachable during the build? I have posted this issue in Quarkus Github


This artifact:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-junit5-mockito</artifactId>
        </dependency>

should be scoped test.
